# Need to extract specific data from a json object

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to extract data from the json object. In the below example I need to extract linkedin url and stackoverflow url without using index. How can i achieve this?

```
{'url': ['https://play.google.com/stores/apps/details?id=com.xcy','https://stackoverflow.com/users/123456/sampath-shanbhag?tab=profile','mailto:sampathshanbhag12@gmail.com','linkedin.com/in/sampathshanbhag']}
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
# r will be the array contains both urls include either stackoverflow or Linkedin
arr = {'url': ['https://play.google.com/stores/apps/details?id=com.xcy','https://stackoverflow.com/users/123456/sampath-shanbhag?tab=profile','mailto:sampathshanbhag12@gmail.com','linkedin.com/in/sampathshanbhag']}
r = [x for x in arr['url'] if 'stackoverflow' in x or 'linkedin' in x]

# Or if u want to get the individual
r = [x for x in arr['url'] if 'stackoverflow' in x ]
r1 = [x for x in arr['url'] if 'linkedin' in x ]
```